# Error occurred While publishing application to Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I just started playing around with Azure platform. I tried to upload a simple application to Azure cloud to see how it works. For that I m using Eclipse Indigo and the eclipse plug-in for Azure. 
However I get the following error while publishing to the cloud:
" Filed uploading deployment package (.cspkg)"
I searched aroudn and I see that other people have the same problem.

The size of the application is 382MB !!!!!  I guess that s why I Get this error.
However why is the size that large?I only have a hello world app with one .jsp file.
When running to the emulator I point to the server installation that I want to use. Is afterwards the whole installation being uploaded to the cloud while publishing? Even in this case , I use Tomcat which is about 50 MB? Where are the rest 230Mb  coming from ?
How can i reduce the size of my app?
I d also like to know whether the Eclipse plug-in for Azure is supported by Eclipse Indigo. I read on the Azure site that Eclipse Helios is required.